# Haskell number input and output

Tags: haskell, numbers

I am trying to code something in Haskell and can't find a breakthrough. What I'm trying to do, is from GHCi input one pair of numbers, do some equations with them and print out results. Let say the input is (a,b). Equations could be as simple as c = b **2 + a **3 - sin b and d = a - b 
The output should be (c,d). Is it possible to do it and how.

Comment: What do you mean by “from GHCi input one pair of numbers”? From what _source_? If you're in GHCi, why don't you just _define_ those variables with `let`? And, how is this problem specific to _numbers_?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample ghci session:

```
> a = 3
> b = 4
> (b**2 + a**3 - sin b, a - b)
(43.75680249530793,-1)
```

If this does not meet your needs, you will need to be more specific about your needs (preferably in a fresh question that refers to this one and explains why the new question is different from this one).

Comment: Hi, the task I'm trying to do is to convert geodetic coordinates to plate coordinates. Equations are quite long, so the end user of script can't write them down so easily and directly in GHCI. The code should be written in file, which is then compiled. User is asked to write pair of geodetic coordinates and the result is pair of plate coordinates. Example of input in decimal degrees (46.0010, 15.2300) and output (480394.43, 5123454.21). Something as on [link]
http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Ellipsoidal_and_Cartesian_Coordinates_Conversion

Comment: @NikolaKranjcic I encourage you to open a fresh question with that description of your goals, some details about what you have tried to make that work, and what went wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Thank you, I will open a new question. :)